# Finding unique element in a long array gives segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, arrays, g++

I was given a problem to find unique elements in a array formed by using modulo operator over a long integers. So I have written code as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    long n;
    long s;
    long p;
    long q;
    long temp;
    long mod= pow(2, 31);

    cin >> n >> s >> p >> q;

    long array[n];

    array[0] = (s % mod);

    for(long i = 1; i < n; i++){
        temp = array[i-1]*p+q;
        array[i] = (temp % mod);
    }

    set<long> result(array, array + n);
    cout << result.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

For smaller input the code runs perfectly fine. When it get tested for input:

```
100000000 1506922183 1236189611 306853238
```

It is giving the segmentation fault error. 
Where I am going wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Alphabet soup naming is a disincentive to debugging.

Comment: I am guessing, [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bitset-1) is the problem you are trying to solve?. If so, you will need to use a bit array, possibly, `std::vector<bool>`. But there is a further optimization where you do not need to store all the values taking advantage of the fact that repetition will only happen if a previous value is equal to the next.

Comment: Similar problem is given...

Answer (score 2):

`long array[n];` is not Standard C++. In addition, given a sufficiently large `n` it will overrun your Automatic storage and make you have a very bad day. Consider using `std::vector<long> array(n);` instead.

The math:

`long array[n];` with your input resolves to `long array[100000000];`

[`long` is at least 4 bytes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)  This means you are asking for a minimum of 100000000 * 4 bytes = 400000000 bytes = around 400 MB Automatic Storage.

Typical Automatic data store is a stack of approximately 1-10 MB.

Comment: When using vector it hangs without any output.

Comment: @AbhijatyaSingh `set<long> result(array.begin(), array.end());` is insanely expensive  with a hundred million elements. Wait a while. Actually, rethink your algorithm.

Comment: Another small niggle: `long mod= pow(2, 31);` has room for weirdness and improvement. You should get the same result from `long mod= 1 << 31;`

Comment: And stopping to think about that for a second, if long is 32 bits, you've wandered into signed overflow.

Comment: Thats correct ong mod= 1 << 31; get the same result and same issue as pow(2, 31).

Comment: use `1ul << 31`   (1 << 31 is implementation-defined and likely to be a negative number if 32-bit ints)

Answer (score 2):

On one side VLA is not legal C++ code, on another you do not need that array at all - you just waste memory:

```
cin >> n >> s >> p >> q;

set<long> result;
long value = 0;
for(long i = 0; i < n; i++){
    value = ( i == 0 ? s : value * p + q ) % mod;
    result.insert( value );
}

cout << result.size() << endl;
```

To speed up you code consider using `std::unordered_set` instead of `std::set`

Comment: Testing team is created test cases like that.

Comment: Then wait till it terminates of fix it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
vector<long>  v;
v.push_back(s % mod);
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    long temp = v[i-1] * p + q;
    v.push_back(temp % mod);
}
```

This way you will not have to define the size of the vector and let it handle it dynamically.

Comment: This code hangs the execution and terminal goes still

Comment: This is happening because the size of the vector becomes so large that it can't be allocated in the stack and thus it hangs. I went to the problem you're trying to solve and it will need bit array to be implemented with optimizations.